# Using Nvidia GeForce 8600 GT and Intel HD 4000 at same time

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

I have been running Ubuntu in a VM at work for a while now to do my programming in and finally got sick of windows and decided to go full Ubuntu. I can't seem to get my 3 monitors to work. When I first installed ubuntu all three monitors come on but you can tell no video drivers are installed because the mouse is blinking when you move it around and dragging windows is a little glitchy. So I searched for hours the other day and tried several things I found online with no success. I finally just reinstalled ubuntu and installed the Nvidia GeForce driver and I'm just dealing with 2 monitors until I can figure out the fix for this. There has to be a simple solution to this that I am just failing to realize.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with Nvidia GeForce 8600 GT and Intel HD 4000.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

NOTE: I'm also running the Z77 Extreme4 motherboard. The Intel HD 4000 is the on board video. I had no problems in Windows 8.1 getting all 3 monitors to work (2 on the nvidia card and 1 on the on board video).

Comment: Can you give more specifics? Is the hardware correctly detected? What does your `xorg.conf` file look like? Specifically, it's important that you identify (using `BusID PCI:...`) which driver to use for your Geforce adapter and which is your i915.